# Compute a sequence of number whose with fixed min distance and max distance

Tags: javascript, math, d3.js

Is there a way to generate `n` numbers whose space between them grows incrementally and which that space varies between a min value and a max value? It's not important the domain of these numbers.

I immagine to call a function like this:

```js
const serie = computeSerie(n, minSpace, maxSpace) 

// domain is not important, for example [1, +infinity] but also [0, 1], what you prefer

const serie1 = computeSerie(5, 1, 1) // [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
const serie2 = computeSerie(5, 2, 2) // [1, 3, 5, 7, 9]
const serie3 = computeSerie(5, 1, 4) // [1, ...] I don't know, I suppose to use a pow math function (?)
const serie4 = computeSerie(7, 1, 6) // [1, 2, 4, 8, 13, 18, 24]
```

Visually:

```
serie1: |-|-|-|-|
serie2: |--|--|--|--|
serie3: |-|???|--| 
serie4: |-|--|---|----|-----|------|
```

I've no idea how to implement this, maybe d3 could be useful but how?

Thank a lot for every tip

Comment: I don't get the idea what are you trying to do here but have you tried using loops?

Comment: @LeoRamadani I added a visual example and another serie, I hope now is more clear

Comment: I don't think you need d3 at all to do what you're doing. Why does a min space of 1 and a max space of 6 produce this array tho: `[1, 2, 4, 8, 13, 18, 24]`? What is the increment criteria?

Comment: @Terry in my example the criteria is simply +1. But I've not a clear idea about which is the best way to obtain something like an incremental sequences of numbers with a fixed start and end distance..
Visually the result should be similar to `|-|--|---|----|-----|------|`

Comment: But 2 -> 4 is not +1. 4 -> 8 is not +1. 13 -> 18 is not +1... so on and so forth. It's not clear what you're asking: do you need help with generating the array, or help with visualizing it?

Comment: +1 compared to the previous distance.
I need help with generating the array and I don't know how to explain what I need, I think visualizing the problem simplify what I'm trying to build

Comment: There's a way to linearly increase the gap in each step, but do you need the resulting values to all be integers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work, but if your `minSpace` and `maxSpace` values don't match up with `n` you will get fractional values too. (Can do a `Math.floor/ceil/round` for those?)

```js
function computeSerie(n, minSpace, maxSpace) {
  const step = (maxSpace - minSpace) / (n - 2)
  const arr = []
  const startAt = 1
  arr.push(startAt)
  for (let i = 1; i < n; i++) {
    arr.push(arr[i - 1] + minSpace + (i - 1) * step)
  }
  return arr
}

console.log(computeSerie(5, 1, 1)) // [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
console.log(computeSerie(5, 2, 2)) // [1, 3, 5, 7, 9]
console.log(computeSerie(5, 1, 4)) // [1, 2, 4, 7, 11]
console.log(computeSerie(7, 1, 6)) // [1, 2, 4, 7, 11, 16, 22]

// will get fractional values for this
console.log(computeSerie(7, 1, 5)) // [1, 2, 3.8, 6.4, 9.8, 14, 19]
```